# Qt: add QPlainTextEdit in new tab

Tags: qt, tabs, qt-designer

A lot of Qt questions from me :) I have a class called MainWindow. Here I have menus (file, edit, settings), toolbar buttons (new, open etc) and a tabContainer. Each tab represents a new file (making a simple c++ editor). In addition, I have another class containing a QPlainTextEdit, and certain functions to manipulate the text within the editor. But have can I connect these two classes? So that I create a new object of this class in each of the tabs? I am using Qt Creator, if these is a simple way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Your case isn't going to be possible to draw "declaratively" in Qt Designer...because it's a pattern of "N tabs" (as opposed to drawing a fixed form).  So you probably want to start with zero tabs and then have a function that makes new tabs with code--rather than trying to lay out your control inside of a "sample" tab and expect Qt to copy it for you.  But for future reference: http://www.tinesoft.com/qt/use-custom-widgets-with-qt-designer-promotion-technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mainWindow::on_NewFile_triggered()
{
  tabWidget->addTab( new TextEditor );
}
```

What else do you need? What have you done, and what is not working?

Comment: Worked with `tabWidget->addTab( new QPlainTextEdit, "TabName" );`
Thanks!